# How to sort mongo aggregate query based on results inner object

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-mvc

If mongo aggregation result is:

```
{
  _id : "5c1a39d182ceb728c3430275",
  docs : {
    "First Name": "Nilesh",
    "Last Name" : "Sodha",
    "Age"       : 23    
  }
},

{
  _id : "5c1a39d182ceb728c3430274",
  docs : {
    "First Name": "Pradip",
    "Last Name" : "Sodha",
    "Age"       : 25    
  }
}
```

How to get sorted result based on "Age" in JAVA

Comment: Could you show your query? You could sort the data by modifying your aggregation query (add sort command). For example: "db.users.find().sort( { username : 1, age : -1 } );"

Comment: aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
        match(criteria),
        group("First Name").push(ROOT).as("docs"),
        sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "Age");

In this sort is not working
@SergeyChepurnov

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 mongoTemplate.find(new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(mongoId))
                    .with(new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "Age")), eClass);
```

> mongoId = autogenerated mongo id

Comment: this is for normal mongo find query with sort but I want to use in aggregate query.